# What is Chrome Canary and how is it different from Google Chrome - for Linux users?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-canary

> Chrome has 3 releases - a regular release, a dev release and canary.
>   Canary is simply a much newer release thats not as well tested, but
>   has the latest shiny stuff. After a while the version that was
>   released in the canary channel gets any bugs that are found fixed,
>   then filters downward to dev, and then to the regular release. Other
>   than the lack of testing, and possibly not having all the bugs fixed,
>   canary is merely chrome FROM THE FUTURE
>
> In short, you get cool stuff, but it might crash horribly. On the
>   other hand, you don't have to use it as a primary (in fact, you cannot
>   set it as default) browser. Its mainly useful if you like living
>   dangerously and want to test bleeding edge features

Bit confuse.

Well Canary is the latest and the rest is for stable use like others said FROM the FUTURE.

But this question is about Linux user point of view. As i am 100% (CentOS, Fedora, ArchLinux, Ubuntu, FreeBSD) user and i unfortunately do not have permanent Mac or Windows development hardware/software.

How can i get Google Canary? When someone say please debug it with only Google Canary not with Google Chrome Browser or Chromium browser???

Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That looks awefully familiar](https://superuser.com/a/582320/10165) and there's a [partial answer](https://superuser.com/questions/582295/what-is-chrome-canary-and-how-is-it-different-from-google-chrome/582320#comment712851_582320) to your question in the comments

There's no official canary release for linux - There's releases for windows, and I believe OS X only. If you *really* must run canary in linux, it does seem to work in wine. Canary merely is an official, nightly build for windows and OS X.

[The official explaination](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-discuss/GNE4pEXLMkQ/cis32ewLosYJ) is that the nightly builds of chromium work perfectly well (other than a few plugins) due to logistical reasons. I suppose since linux covers a wider array of distributions, and hardware.

If you REALLY need a bleeding edge chrome build, go with a nightly build for the distribution or try it out in wine.